# how to make Chrome remember previously ajax submitted form info (for autocomplete)?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, google-chrome, form-submit

I'm using Google Chrome to submit a form with jQuery.ajax (and using return false to stop the page from reloading), the issue is that I want the inputs to remember the previously submitted values (for autocompleting, so it'd be any of them, not just the previous one, as they can vary a lot, and so I don't have to type all over again if it'll be the same thing), however, I've noticed new data isn't remembered unless it was submitted the normal way. Is there a way to make Chrome "remeber" (as in suggesting the if I start typing something that matches a previously submitted value) new submitted values for the inputs by submitting with ajax?

P.S. I'm writing all the code, so I can do any necessary change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use local session or local storage. That way, when you load the form, the first thing that you  do is check if the browser's storage has the form's value; if it does, then populate the form with these values.

There is also the option of doing server-side session storage but local storage should be an easier path.

Comment: would local session or local storage help in storing just a single value, or would it store multiple options (to match the user's current input)?

Comment: it can store as many values (or as few) as you need; up to 5MB. And it's really easy to implement too.

Comment: ok, let me know; it should work just fine for you. Happy coding.

Comment: We are talking about something that the browser should take care off not that we have to code in order to store in the local storage... it is not a useful answer at all